# Terraform get json data from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a EMR using Terraform. I am able to specify a local file to configurations parameter but I want to know if it's possible to specify a json file in S3 and if so how.

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  configurations = "${file("local/file/path/to/json/file")}"
  ...
  ...
}
```

What I want is be able to specify a s3 file path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`aws_s3_bucket_object` data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/s3_bucket_object.html) to retrieve an object's content from S3:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "config" {
  bucket = "example-bucket"
  key = "config.json"
}

resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
  configurations = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.config.body}"
}
```